# JQuery unrecognized expression on Json response data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to highlight days in a Zabuto calendar with data that I get from an Ajax response, but I keep getting a `Syntax error, unrecognized expression` on the returned data.

I'm using jquery-3.2.1 and Zabuto Calendar to display the days.

The response data:.

```
[
    {"date":"2018-03-26","badge":false,"title":"Example 1"},
    {"date":"2018-03-28","badge":false,"title":"Example 2"}
]
```

What I've tried

```
    var eventData = "";
    var eventsDataUrl = "my_url"; 
    $.get(eventsDataUrl, function (returnEventData) {                           
        eventData = returnEventData;            
    }); 

    $("#events-calendar").zabuto_calendar({             
        data: eventData,
        today: true,                
        show_days: true,
        nav_icon: {
          prev: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
          next: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'
        }
    });
```

Comment: if you are doing it in the order I see here, `eventData` will be empty when you assign it to your calendar via `data: eventData`, mostly because your `$.get` response may not have returned data yet.

Comment: try putting the call to `zabuto_calendar` INSIDE the callback from `.get`, right after `eventData = returnEventData;`

Comment: @J.M.Echevarría your suggestion doesn't work for me